# How to break one mysql table into two parts which import in pdf using iText?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, pdf, itext

I am creating a JSP project, in which I generate pdf-files of a MySQL table using iText. But my some tables have more columns, so I want to make that table into two parts.
I am using NetBeans IDE for that. Below is my code. Please tell me how the write the code for breaking the table into two parts.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/GlHSM";  
    String user = "root"; //Username of database  
    String pass1 = ""; //Password of database 
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass1);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();  
    ResultSet query = stmt.executeQuery("select * from CardInformation");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    Document PDFLogReport = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(PDFLogReport,response.getOutputStream());
    PDFLogReport.open(); 
    PDFLogReport.add(new Paragraph("Card Information: \n"));
    PDFLogReport.add(new Paragraph(" "));
    PdfPTable LogTable = new PdfPTable(12); 
    PdfPCell table_cell;
    table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Index"));
    table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
    table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Card No"));
    table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
    table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("PIN Block"));
    table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
    table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Card Expiry"));
    table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
    table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Issue Date"));
    table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
    table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("PIN Retries"));
    table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
    table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("BIO Retries"));
    table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
    table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Is Blocked"));
    table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
    table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Block Date Time"));
    table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
    table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Created By"));
    table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
    table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date Created"));
    table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
    table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Card Type"));
    table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
    LogTable.setHeaderRows(1);
    while(query.next()){
        String fname = query.getString("Indx");
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(fname));
        table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);  
        LogTable.addCell(table_cell);  
        String lname = query.getString("CardNo");  
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(lname));  
        table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
        String date = query.getString("PINBlock");  
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(date));  
        table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
        String gender = query.getString("CardExpiry");  
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(gender));  
        table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
        String gender2 = query.getString("IssueDate");  
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(gender2));  
        table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
        String pin = query.getString("PINRetries");  
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(pin));  
        table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
        String dob = query.getString("BIORetries");  
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dob));  
        table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
        String con = query.getString("IsBlocked");  
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(con));  
        table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
        String cr = query.getString("BlockDateTime");  
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cr));  
        table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
        String da = query.getString("CreatedBy");  
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(da));  
        table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
        String pan = query.getString("DateCreated");  
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(pan));  
        table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
        String cty = query.getString("CardType");  
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cty));  
        table_cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        LogTable.addCell(table_cell);
    }
PDFLogReport.add(LogTable);
PDFLogReport.close();  
query.close();
stmt.close();   
conn.close();
```

Comment: Define "two parts". iText automatically distributes a table over different pages if the rows of a table don't fit the page. You have a table with 12 columns. Why don't you create pages in landscape instead of in portrait. Also: the subject of your question sounds like you want two sub-queries; the body of your question sounds as if you're talking about splitting a table in iText. You don't explain if the table needs to be split vertically or horizontally. You don't explain what the problem is. You should past an enormous code sample and expect us to guess what you're asking.

Comment: my table have 12 columns so i want to make two table for that one table. in first table out of 12 column 6 column will display and on same page the next table will create with remaining 6 columns of my original 12 column table.

Comment: Can you give some kind of example for the context you are asking. You need to clear your question.

Comment: Suppose this is my table 
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 | Column7 | Column8 |

So i want two split that table into two parts like:
Table 1:
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | 

Table2:
| Column5 | Column6 | Column7 | Column8 | 

Bothe tables have in one page only

Comment: This has already been explained in the answers to the questions [How to span wide tables across multiple pages horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502122) and [iTextSharp PdfPtable multipage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313320). Please don't post duplicate questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to span wide tables across multiple pages horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502122/how-to-span-wide-tables-across-multiple-pages-horizontally)